# How to charge previous (When my app was free) user after make it paid?

Tags: iphone, ios5

My iphone app was free for long term. I ve made it paid any more . But i want to charge people who already owns it if they want to update, i dont want to allow them to get updates unless they pay. I ve seen some apps are asking for paid uptades but i dont know how to do that, any idea ?

Comment: good luck with that, now what's your programming question?

Comment: [This proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores) is a better place for this question.

Answer (score 1):

You really can't do this, as it goes against Apple's payment model. The only way to do this is to lock your content and make it available via in-app purchase.

Comment: But i when i try to update an app (i dont remember if it was already paid or it was free)  it says '' you have not owned a previous major version of this software. You have to buy it at full price Would you like to buy it ? '' .

Answer (score 1):

Call that one the free version and don't update it anymore (except for bug fixes) and create a new program and start charging for it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, what you see in this other app for sure is just an **in-app purchase**.

All you have to do is to hide all your functionality behind if statements (if (fullVersionBought) {...}), and implement an in-app purchase that unlocks the features. You can then prompt the users to upgrade when they start your app.

For implementing in-app purchases, you can have a look here, it's not that hard:

https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKStoreKit

This way, all users of your app cannot access the functionality anymore, except when they buy the upgrade to the full version. Whether that's a good idea is another question, it might annoy quite some of your users to not be able to use any functionality anymore and being forced to pay all of a sudden.